# SQL query using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table called "EMP" and two collumns one called "deptno" and the other called "job". I need a query to find out how many people there are in each type of job within each department.

I know I need to use count() and group by but im not sure how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks James.

Comment: Any sample data and the desired output please?

Comment: SELECT JOB, count(JOB)
  FROM EMP
  GROUP BY JOB;

This is the answer I have made from all the suggestions, thank you for the help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select job, deptno, count(*) as people
from emp
group by job, deptno
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT JOB, DEPTNO, count(1) AS EMP_COUNT
  FROM EMP
  GROUP BY JOB, DEPTNO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select job, deptno, count(*) as TotEmp
from emp
group by job, deptno
```